# How do EMACS Lisp programmers read text files for non-editing purposes?

Tags: file-io, emacs, elisp

What do EMACS Lisp programmers do, when they want to write something roughly the equivalent of...

```
for line in open("foo.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8").readlines():
    ...(split on ws and call a fn, or whatever)...
```

..?

When I look in the EMACS lisp help, I see functions about opening files into text editing buffers -- not exactly what I was intending.  I suppose I could write functions to visit the lines of the file, but if I did that, I wouldn't want the user to see it, and besides, it doesn't seem very efficient from a text-processing standpoint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think a more direct translation of the original Python code is as follows:

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert-file-contents "foo.txt")
  (while (search-forward-regexp "\\(.*\\)\n?" nil t)
    ; do something with this line in (match-string 1)
    ))
```

I think `with-temp-buffer`/`insert-file-contents` is generally preferable to `with-current-buffer`/`find-file-noselect`, because the former guarantees that you're working with a fresh copy of the entire file contents.  With the latter construction, if you happen to already have a buffer visiting the target file, then that buffer is returned by `find-file-noselect`, so if that buffer has been narrowed, you'll only see that part of the file when you process it.

Keep in mind that it may very well be more convenient **not** to process the file line-by-line.  For example, this is an expression that returns a list of all sequences of consecutive digits in the file:

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert-file-contents "foo.txt")
  (loop while (search-forward-regexp "[0-9]+" nil t)
        collect (match-string 0)))
```

`(require 'cl)` first to bring in the `loop` macro.

Comment: If processing the file line by line, it is usually faster to use `forward-line` or `end-of-line`.

Comment: In my experience it's a little tricky to identify the end of the file using `forward-line` and kin if the last line may or may not end with a newline.

Answer (score 5):

1. Yes, that **is** what you want to do: visit the file in a buffer, and operate on the text in that buffer.
2. You do **not** have to display the buffer, i.e., the user need not see it.
3. And as for efficiency: manipulating text in a buffer is typically the **most** efficient way to manipulate text.

---

You can visit a file in a buffer in several ways.  You might want to use an existing file buffer for this, depending on the use case. That is, if the file is already "open" in Emacs then you might want to use its buffer.

Or you might want to disregard any existing file buffer for an already "open" file, and read the file anew into a new buffer.  For that, as @Sean mentions, you can use `insert-file-contents` with a buffer that you create.  You can create the buffer using `with-temp-buffer` or `generate-new-buffer`, depending, again, on what you want/need to do with it.

If you do want to reuse a buffer that is already visiting the file, you can test whether it has been modified in memory, whether it is narrowed, etc., and do whatever is appropriate for your use case.  You can check whether there is already a buffer visiting the file (using any path/file name) using function `find-buffer-visiting`.

To visit the file, taking advantage of any existing buffer that is visiting it, you can use `find-file-noselect`.  That function returns the buffer that visits the file, so you can pass that buffer as the first argument to `with-current-buffer`.  Here is a simple example.

```el
(with-current-buffer (let ((enable-local-variables  ())) (find-file-noselect file))
  ;; Do some stuff with the text in the buffer.
  ;; Optionally save the buffer back to the file.
  )
```

(The binding of `enable-local-variables` to `nil` is a minor optimization, for the common case where you don't need to bother with buffer-local variables.)

Comment: The problem with `find-file-noselect` is what happens if the user is already visiting the file.  That's why it's better to use `insert-file` in a temp buffer, as in Sean's answer.

Comment: @jch: No, the generalization "it's better" is wrong. It all depends on what you want/need to do - the devil of the solution/implementation is in the details of the problem/requirement. The important answer to the question is what I've put up front, as 1, 2, 3. The question as posed is based on a misunderstanding, which 1, 2, 3 should clear up.